# Is a warrant required to access your SMS activity in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, search-and-seizure

How long is it saved and under what circumstances can it be retrieved by the state?

Comment: By "SMS activity" are you referring to the actual message contents or just metadata (time/sender/recever etc.)?

Comment: I guess the contents but information about the treatment of metadata is interesting to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they need a court order. The cellphone provider is obligated to keep your data for at least 6 months. Any circumstance that warrants a search warrant.

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly governed by the *[Investigatory Powers Act 2016](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/contents)*, a good summary of the state of things after the limiting *[Tele2/Watson](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=186492&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=12734396)* Court of Justice of the European Union (CJEU) ruling is available on *[Technology Law Dispatch](https://www.technologylawdispatch.com/2018/12/regulatory/uk-government-introduces-data-retention-and-acquisition-regulations-2018/)*. [Section 227](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/section/227) of the Act sets up a committee of Judicial Commissioners (JC) led by an Investigatory Powers Commissioner (IPC) who are empowered to make these data privacy decisions. These are judges or former judges appointed by the Prime Minister with approval of the Lord Chancellor and chief justices of the 3 main judiciaries (though strangely enough, it doesn't seem the President of the Supreme Court is required here).

In general, it is more difficult to obtain the contents of your SMS messages than the SMS metadata like sender, recipient, and time. The SMS message itself is referred to as *content* in the legal text while the metadata is *communications data* ([s. 261](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/section/261)).

In brief, for a set of various defined purposes, the Secretary of State with approval from a JC can issue a retention order to your provider which forces them to store the specified communications data for up to **12 months** ([s. 87](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/section/87)). Independently of whether a retention order was issued, communications data may be compelled by authorization of either the IPC or a designated senior officer for various purposes depending on the scenario ([s. 60A](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/section/60A), [s. 61](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/section/61), [s. 61A](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/section/61A)). While the [defined list of designated senior officers](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/schedule/4) is rather large, outside of emergencies they are restricted to compelling communications data for the purposes of investigating crime or national security ([s. 61(7)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/section/61)).

Warrants provide more avenues for obtaining communications data and can reach into the contents as well. The act defines interception warrants, equipment interference (hacking) warrants, bulk versions of both in addition to bulk acquisition and bulk personal dataset warrants (that last one not entirely related to this question). These warrants generally require JC approval. Interception and hacking warrants can reach into the content, acquisition is restricted to communications data. Respecting the *Tele2/Watson* ruling, these warrants are generally restricted to investigating serious crime (possibility of 12 or more months of jail time) or national security. The bulk interception and bulk hacking warrants are also restricted to primarily targetting communication originating or terminating overseas.

I haven't read too much beyond this Act and I'm not too familiar with UK criminal law, but I imagine ordinary search warrants, production orders or something similar exist for scenarios that don't fall into serious crime or national security. However, while it's hard to prove a negative, I can't find any reference that the government can compel a service provider to specifically store SMS content (though I imagine temporary storage may be technically necessary to fulfil an interception warrant). Generally warrants are to obtain something rather immediately and in any case the content could be encrypted with the provider being unable to decrypt depending on their setup. I could be wrong though.

Finally, I'll note that this is an area of legislation that is not settled. The UK has traditionally legislated for greater surveillance powers, though has been limited in succession by the CJEU in *[Digital Rights Ireland](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=150642&pageIndex=0&doclang=en&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=12734536)*, *[Tele2/Watson](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=186492&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=12734396)* and potentially the upcoming *[Privacy International](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=222262&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=req&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=12733486)*, a case referred by the Investigatory Powers Tribunal where the non-binding AG opinion is that the bulk acquisition warrant does not comply with EU law in the context of *Tele2/Watson*. While Brexit has occurred, the UK is generally still required to follow EU law during the transition period and in any case the results of the CJEU rulings have largely been reflected in domestic law. However post-transition, it's very possible that the UK will re-legislate for this, though at the same time, the recent *[Schrems II](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=228677&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=req&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=9714625)* decision suggests that doing so will [complicate future trade relations with the EU in light of the GDPR](https://iapp.org/news/a/what-does-the-schrems-ii-judgement-mean-for-the-uk-and-eu-uk-data-flows/).

Comment: Wow, what a comprehensive answer! I'd just like to ask, what is the transition period, during which EU law will still bind the UK, defined as?

Comment: @JosephP. See the [Withdrawal Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit_withdrawal_agreement) for specifics, but the transition period is defined to end 31 December 2020. I haven't followed Brexit news in a while, but apparently, there's [no longer a straightforward way to extend this deadline](https://ukandeu.ac.uk/can-the-brexit-transition-period-still-be-extended/.)